# ProviderFunction not exporting my new functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, yarn-workspaces

**My Problem :**
I expect my `FirebaseProvider` function to provide an object containing all functions, through the app. The problem is that all functions are well provided through my files, except my last new function : `fetchTest`.

**Explainations :**
If I click the `TestPage.js` button I get `Uncaught TypeError: fetchTest is not a function`.
I saw many posts on stackoverflow about this type of error, but none did help me. -> I think the original problem is the `index.js` is not called. The `console.log("firebaseprovider")` (in `index.js`) does not appear in console, yet the other files of the project in `web-app/src/views/` have the same imports and exports than `TestPage`.

Since `App.js` code worked fine on all the other files, I don't know how `console.log("firebaseprovider")` is never displayed in the navigator console. (**edit**: no matter which page I go, this `console.log` never appears)
`<FirebaseProvider>` seems to not provide `TestPage.js`.
Do you have an idea ?

What I've tried :

- placing a `console.log` in `TestPage.js` : it shows every function written in `index.js` but not `fetchTest`. It seems to not be properly exported through `api` object.
- in `TestPage.js` trying `console.log("api.fetchTest")` : console displays `undefined`.
- add a second testing function in `index.js`, whithout parameters, which just does `console.log("test")`
- compare `imports`/`exports` and `api` declarations with other files in `web-app/src/views/`
- create a `handleSubmit()` function in `TestPage.js` to not put the functions directly in `return`
- delete `node_modules` and then `yarn install`
- `yarn workspace web-app build` and then relaunch `yarn workspace web-app start`

(This is a Yarn Workspaces project containing a `common/` and a `web-app/` folders)

common/src/**index.js**:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import {FirebaseConfig} from 'config';

const FirebaseContext = createContext(null);
const FirebaseProvider  = ({ children }) => {
    console.log("firebaseprovider");  // is not displayed in the console
    let firebase = { app: null, database: null, auth: null, storage:null }

    if (!app.apps.length) {  // I tried to comment out this line (and the '}') -> no difference
        app.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);  // no difference when commented out
        firebase = {
            app: app,
            database: app.database(),
            auth: app.auth(),
            storage: app.storage(),
            // [ ... ] other lines of similar code
            api : {  // here are functions to import
              fetchUser: () => (dispatch) => fetchUser()(dispatch)(firebase),
              addProfile: (details) => (dispatch) => addProfile(userDetails)(dispatch)(firebase),
              // [ ... ] other functions, properly exported and working in other files
              // My function :
              fetchTest: (testData) => (dispatch) => fetchTest(testData)(dispatch)(firebase),
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>
            {children}
        </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    )
}
export { FirebaseContext, FirebaseProvider, store }
```

web-app/src/views/**TestPage.js**:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { FirebaseContext } from "common";

const TestPage.js = () => {
  const { api } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  console.log(api);  // Displays all functions in api object, but not fetchTest
  const { fetchTest } = api;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const testData = { validation: "pending" };
  return <button onClick={ () => {
    dispatch(fetchTest(testData));  // Tried with/without dispatch
    alert("done");
  }}>Test button</button>
}
export default TestPage;
```

web-app/src/**App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// ... import all pages
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import TestPage from './views/CreateSiteNeed';  // written same way  for the other pages
import { store, FirebaseProvider } from 'common';
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FirebaseProvider>
        <AuthLoading>
          <Router history={hist}>
            <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact component={MyProfile} path="/profile" />
              <!-- [ ... ] more <ProtectedRoute /> lines, form imported Pages line 3. -->
              <ProtectedRoute exact component={TestPage} path="/testpage" />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </AuthLoading>
      </FirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I hope some people will find this post helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem :

**Firstly :**
I'm using Redux, so `fetchTest()` has its `testActions.js` and `testReducer.js` files, which are functionnal. But I did forget to update my `store.js` :

```
// [ ... ] import all reducers
import { testReducer as testData } from '../reducers/testReducer'; // was'nt imported

const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth,
  usersdata,
  // [ ... ] other imported reducers
  testData  // My test reducer
}
// The rest is a classic store.js code
```

**Secondly :**
As I'm using Yarn Workspaces, I had to compile the code in `common/dist/index.js` to make it accessible through the whole entire code (even for local testing).
Here is the command to compile the code (-> to include all redux edits made above) and make it accessible to `web-app` workspace :

```
yarn workspace common build && yarn workspace web-app add common@1.0.0 --force
```

Explanations on the second part of the command (`yarn workspace web-app add common@1.0.0 --force`) :
The `web-app/package.json` file contains `{ "dependencies": { ... "common":"1.0.0" ... }}`